# How to play Dolby in the car via carplay？

Tags: carplay, dolby

According to "CarPlay adds development support for Spatial Audio in iOS 17.2, giving automakers the ability to enable an immersive sound experience in vehicles with multichannel audio capabilities. Spatial Audio with support for Dolby Atmos can also be implemented in compatible vehicles. CarPlay users will also have access to an ever-growing selection of Spatial Audio songs and albums available in Apple Music and third-party apps."
How can i play Dolby in car via carplay?
As developer, how can I make my APP support this function?

As developer, how can I make my APP support this function?